# Instantiated prefab size is too big Unity C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, object, unity-game-engine

When i instantiate my prefab

```
        copyOfSpellObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Item_Spell itemSpell = copyOfSpellObject.GetComponent<Item_Spell>();
        itemSpell.SpellObject = GetComponent<Item_Spell>().SpellObject;
        copyOfSpellObject.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
        copyOfSpellObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 0));
        copyOfSpellObject.transform.SetParent(transform.parent.parent.parent, false);
```

It becomes ultra big

Normal - http://prntscr.com/btgzg7

Big - http://prntscr.com/btgzke

Why is that ? The problem occurs only when I put the gameobject as a child to a specific parents, more specifically, each parent after this one will cause the problem including this `transform.parent.parent.parent`.

Comment: You are setting twice the parent. Is there a reason for that? Also the second call looks weird, maybe you want to use transform.root instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the object in the hierarchy after instantiating it. Do you see any large numbers in the 'scale' property (in the transform component)? If you do, try setting those numbers all to 1 and see if that's the size you want. Then just set the scale of the object to 1 (or whatever size you like) in your code like this:

```
copyOfSpellObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(gameObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Item_Spell itemSpell = copyOfSpellObject.GetComponent<Item_Spell>();
    itemSpell.SpellObject = GetComponent<Item_Spell>().SpellObject;
    copyOfSpellObject.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
    copyOfSpellObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 0));
    copyOfSpellObject.transform.SetParent(transform.parent.parent.parent, false);
    copyOfSpellObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

The transform tends to get really weird when parenting an instantiated object originally created without a parent.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: This kinda solves my problem, if I put the parent to be `transform.root` it's still too big.

Comment: @preqlsusspermaohranitel Where did you create the actual prefab? Did you just create the object (without a parent) and saved it as a prefab? Because if you did, that's probably where your problem is. You should create the object inside its parent (in the editor), adjust the size to how you want, and then save it as a prefab. Them when you go to instantiate the object, everything should stay the same.